# Gnome 3 - how can I turn on some extention?

Tags: gnome, gnome-tweak-tool

I've got fresh Ubuntu Gnome (14) installed on new workstation and for some reason it does not show up a list of opened windows so I need to click activities to change window.

Obviously it's annoying when I work with multiple applications at once. I've looked out that I should turn on `Window list` extension but when I switch from off to on in tweak tool nothing happens.

There's no `apply` button or something. Also when I restart tweak tool it's still set to off. How can I turn it on???

Is it possible to have multiple bars? One for each monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the GNOME extension page [Window List by fmuellner](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/602/window-list/)  in Firefox. In use the slider to activate the extension

[image]

The extension is available for GNOME 3.0 ... 3.16

[image]

I have only a single monitor setup, therefore I can't check, if it's possible to have multiple bars.

Comment: I tried but when I refresh page it's off again - is there some dependency?

Comment: No, My GNOME is a standard installation. Can you test the extension with another user?

Comment: System restart helped... :o